# How to retrieve JSON object from JSON array using Cloudant Query

Tags: json, cloudant

I have saved document in cloudant DB in below format. I want to retrieve JSON object which value is KEY="Test1". Below is the save document structure.

```
{
  "_id": "SOCIALKEYWORD",
  "_rev": "3-5b46ffc64d05858e15f443b1115d97be",
  "KEYWORD": [
    {
      "KEY": "Test1",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    },
    {
      "KEY": "@IdeaCellular",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    },
    {
      "KEY": "@idea_cares",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created index on KEY & KEYWORD separately of type JSON
I have written below query but no result came.

```
{
  "selector": {
        "_id" : "SOCIALKEYWORD"
  },
  "include_fields": [
    "KEY",
    "SITEID",
    "STATUS"
  ]
}
```

please tell me the correct query

Comment: Please change all occurrences of "Jason" to "json" unless you are referring to someone directly.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Check under key/keys: https://docs.cloudant.com/using_views.html?http

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you're expecting for query results? I see two immediate issues with what you've outlined. The first issue is that you don't need to create an index on the `KEY` or `KEYWORD` field if you're going to just query against the `_id` field as you do in your query example (there is a special index on the `_id` field). Having these two extra indexes won't cause any problems, but it creates two unnecessary indexes. The second issue is that in your query you have to indicate a top level field or fields to return. Try this query instead:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id" : "SOCIALKEYWORD"
  },
  "fields": [
    "KEYWORD"
  ]
}
```

This query should give you the following results:

```
{
  "KEYWORD": [
    {
      "KEY": "Test1",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    },
    {
      "KEY": "@IdeaCellular",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    },
    {
      "KEY": "@idea_cares",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

If instead you're trying to query against `KEY` (nested within `KEYWORD`) then you'll want to create an index on `KEYWORD.KEY` and query against the same.

Comment: I am expecting out put as {
      "KEY": "Test1",
      "SITEID": 1,
      "STATUS": "A"
    }